# How do I prevent Drupal raising a segmentation fault when using a Node.js theming workflow?

Tags: theming, drush

## Symptoms:

Some drush commands fail; Some Drupal pages are blank.
The failing drush commands report "Segmentation fault: 11"
The Apache log (e.g. php-error.log in MAMP) also shows the same error.

## Background:

If you use a gulp or grunt workflow - to compile your theme's SASS etc. - you may run into a problem where drush commands throw a segmentation fault 11 as does Apache whilst serving Drupal pages as blanks (WSDs).

## Probable cause

This is because files from your `grunt` or `gulp` workflow environment in  `node_modules` are erroneously being registered by Drupal itself as a bi-product of `drush cache-clear all` for example. There are dozens of these .js files and Drupal can't handle them ... it's possibly a PCRE regex that is the root cause as this is known elsewhere. Anyway ...

## It doesn't always happen

It's not clear whether some modules (like Browser Sync for example) induce this error as a node.js style (i.e. gulp or grunt) workflow can work perfectly before failing in this way.

Comment: I can confirm Browser Sync & gulp-imagemin were troublesome for me too. Overall .info files in nested folders are the problem.

Comment: FYI: I've met the same issue using ZURB Foundation with Drupal, see issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2514350

Comment: We are trying to fix this in Drupal core. Add your opinion and test patches from this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2329453

Comment: There is an issue for Drupal 7 with a patch that solves the problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/619542 There is a related (less severe) Drupal 8 issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2329453

Comment: This also caused many Drush commands to fail for us (e.g. `drush cc all`), adding to the confusion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the solution you're looking for. Much more elegant and less work:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete"
}
```

Just a slight alteration on @iamcarico's answer above.

note: you may need a .npmrc with just the following content:

```
unsafe-perm = true
```

Comment: It seems to also happen with YML files :(

Answer (score 7):

So, I have a slightly more elegant solution, that will just remove the .info files after npm install. None are needed, so this *Should* be safe.

Add the following to the end of your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "find node_modules/ -name \"*.info\" -type f -delete"
}
```

Comment: The idea to modify package.json files is not so good, as I explain here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2309023#comment-9531611

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

(With many thanks to @jorgegc for identifying the cause in [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2309023#comment-9061529) at d.o. I thought the topic deserved a more general title here.)

1. Move `gulpfile.js` and `package.json` to the new "hidden" directory `.npm`
2. `cd .npm` and `npm install` (after having deleted theme root level `node_modules` directory of course)
3. edit `gulpfile.js` base directory for source and destination file paths.e.g. In the snippet bellow "../" were prepended to paths
4. in turn, invoke `gulp` command from within the `.npm` directory

#### Example directory structure for ihit theme

`.
├── .editorconfig
├── .git
│   ├── HEAD
│   ├── ...
├── .gitignore
├── .jshintrc
├── .npm
│   ├── gulpfile.js
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── package.json
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── js
│   └── sass
├── css
│   ├── ihit.hacks.css
│   └── ihit.styles.css
├── ihit.info
├── ihit.sublime-project
├── ihit.sublime-workspace
├── images
│   ├── logo.png
│   ├── search-icon.png
│   └── sprite.png
├── js
│   └── ihit.behaviors.js
├── php
│   ├── ihit_breadcrumb.inc
│   ├── ihit_form_search_form_alter.inc
│   ├── ihit_menu_link.inc
│   ├── ihit_menu_tree.inc
│   ├── ihit_preprocess_html.inc
│   ├── ihit_preprocess_region.inc
│   └── ihit_process_page.inc
├── research
│   └── Refills
├── screenshot.png
├── template.php
└── templates
    ├── html.tpl.php
    ├── node--image_gallery.tpl.php
    ├── node.tpl.php
    └── page.tpl.php`

#### Head of gulpfile.js

`// project-specific 
var project = {
  path: {
    sass: {
        source: '../assets/sass/**/*.scss',
        css_dest: '../css'
    }, // sass
  .
  .
  .`

Comment: This was the ticket!

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid all of this by installing your workflow tools in the root of the Drupal site. It won't scan a top-level `node_modules` folder.

Installing at root-level also has other benefits, like allowing you to lint your entire project in a uniform fashion (your custom modules, Features, and themes can share this root-level config). Provided you group `sites/all/modules` into `contrib` and `custom` subdirectories, you can easily ignore contrib and other vendor folders.

Comment: We had followed the .npm installation folder trick above your comment previously. Then we switched to Gulp. gulp-eslint does not handle navigating to a parent directory for tracking and linting files. So we moved our build scripts (and node_modules) beside the docroot of our site and everything works perfectly now. thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

It still seems to be a problem and I also got the following error: `Segmentation fault: 11` after running `npm install`.

I use `gulp` version `3.8.11` and `node` with the version `0.12`.

I usually (in this case too) use `aurora` as base theme and use an own `package.json` and `gulp.js` file. My `package.json` file contains [iamcarrico's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/30614/iamcarrico) postinstall script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "find node_modules -type f -name '*.info' | xargs rm;"
  }
```

Hmm, at this point I just recognized that the postinstall script is slightly different which might have caused my Segmentation fault error. Anyway.

What I did was I removed the `node_modules` directory within my theme with `rm -rf ./node_modules`. Cleared the cache with drush `drush cc all`. Then I followed the above instructions of [iainh](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6891/iainh) ... until no. 3 (3 not included), ran `find node_modules -type f -name '*.info' | xargs rm;` inside the `.npm` folder and moved the `gulp.js`, `package.json` and the `node_modules` folder one level up to the original theme folder. I could run `gulp` without segmentation errors and even `browsersync` worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue on drupal.org which addresses this problem, including patch
https://www.drupal.org/node/2329453

Answer (score -1):

my solution was in the past to move the node stuff inside of a hidden folder like ".npm" for example.